# Read more on Database result

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, web

Hi there my code is quite simple but Id like for the design purposes to keep everything neat , at the moment Im pulling all the description which is like Some could be huge others can be quite small , anyway to make it fair I decided to make a read more button and once I click it just expand on the text like , SO somehow to make it show the first 160 characters after that ... then ReadMore link button that when you click it expands and shows the whole text 
Heres my script that I use for now :

```
<p><?PHP echo $thismovie['description']; ?></p> <div style="text-align:right">
```

So I would like to know how this is done and if possible only using javascript, thanks !

Comment: Yes, you use javascript to achieve this.  There are plenty of working examples readily available on the internet on how to achieve this.

Comment: Yes there are but not when the result is commin from mysql , I seem to be a newb at javascript and php not as great either ,and I did look for this before I posted this question Pulling results out of databse + expand text pulled aent easy

Comment: It is easy.  You simply output the entire description and hide the "extra" length of the description using javascript.  If the intent is for the user to be able to click and show the whole description, you will need to load the whole description into the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for PHP way:

```
$firstdesc=substr($thismovie['description'], 0, 160);
```

and when read-more pressed.

```
$totaldesc=substr($thismovie['description'], 160);
```

Ofcourse you can do it with Javascript too.

Comment: So it would be something like:
<p><?PHP echo $firstdesc; ?></p> <div style="text-align:right"><?php echo $totaldesc;?></div>

Comment: @MEX you might wanna add:
if(strlen($thismovie['description']) > 160){
//add read more button..
}
So you don't add it for nothing.

Comment: This does not demonstrate showing the description when more is pressed. Nor does it show a more button. Not the right answer when there are multiple movies on the page as you are forcing your server to concatenate the string twice for each movie description.

Comment: Thankyou this helped me once more !

Answer (score 4):

While you could of course use PHP, another way is to use the text-overflow property of css correctly.

This method will put less strain on the server, especially when there are a bunch of descriptions on the page. Using PHP to concatenate every single one is not efficient and is not the correct way to do this.

Removing a class is much simpler. And you can add it back when you want to show less.

```
<style>
     .ellipsis {
         white-space: nowrap; 
         text-overflow: ellipsis; 
         overflow: hidden; 
         height: 14px;
     }
     .description {
         width: 300px;
         background: #ccc; 
         padding: 3px;
         margin-top: 30px;
         margin-bottom: 0;
     }
</style>

<!-- It is likely you would use a PHP loop for this but for illustration 
     purposes I've listed them out -->

<p class="description ellipsis"><?=$movie[0]['description']?></p>
<a href="#" class="read-more">Read More</a>

<p class="description ellipsis"><?=$movie[1]['description']?></p>
<a href="#" class="read-more">Read More</a>

<p class="description ellipsis"><?=$movie[2]['description']?></p>
<a href="#" class="read-more">Read More</a>

<!-- use as many as you want with no additional strain on server. -->
```

WITH JQUERY... http://jsfiddle.net/kx2nbv3z/

```
<!-- Include jQuery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document)
        .on('click','.read-more',function() { 
            $(this).removeClass('read-more').addClass('show-less').html('Show Less').prev('.description').removeClass('ellipsis'); 
        })

        .on('click','.show-less',function() { 
            $(this).removeClass('show-less').addClass('read-more').html('Read More').prev('.description').addClass('ellipsis'); 
        })
    ;
</script>
```

WITH PURE JAVASCRIPT... http://jsfiddle.net/8wsbw0u8/

```
<script>


if (document.body.addEventListener) {
    document.body.addEventListener('click',yourHandler,false);
}
else {
    document.body.attachEvent('onclick',yourHandler);//for IE
}

function yourHandler(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    prev = target.previousSibling.previousSibling;
    if (target.className.match(/read-more/)) {
        target.className="show-less";
        target.innerHTML = "Show Less";
        prev.setAttribute("class","description");
        console.log(prev);
    }
    else if (target.className.match(/show-less/)) {
        target.className="read-more";
        target.innerHTML = "Read More";
        prev.setAttribute("class","description ellipsis");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes this script is really great I apriciate your answer , but Pulling multiple results out of the database , and when I click on read more it opens for all at the same time , I am currently trying to finish the answer with php and I will show you how i did it ^_^

Comment: See updated answer using classes instead of ids. It puts less overhead on your server, especially when there are a ton of descriptions on the page.

Comment: Also added the ability to reverse the process. See for yourself... http://jsfiddle.net/kx2nbv3z/

Comment: This is working , Thankyou ,I am using this and it works great ! , Is there a way with just javascript ? Jquery is great I will keep it this way because it is looking easy and working I had nothing to edit on yours and didn't figure the php way , it works but this is working just great , thankyou ! Let me know if there is a way not using jquery thankyou !

Comment: Thankyou ,youre a life saver , I owe u One !

Comment: And one question if you don't mind , how do I do to make it detect if it is overflown and if not not to have a readmore button?

Comment: You would loop through the descriptions and detect the length. If it's less than 25 characters (or whatever number fits), hide the read more button. Or use PHP to just not have it on the page. In JavaScript it's String.length and in PHP it's strlen().

Answer (score 1):

use the css style  `text-overflow: ellipsis; and jquery for the full feature.

```js
$('#read-more').click(function() {
    $('#description').css('width','100%');
});
```

```css
#description {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 12em; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="description">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div> <a id="read-more" href="#">Read More</a>
```

Comment: this one wount work for each individual description but the one above worked , thankyou for at least answering , thanks !

Comment: I am glad you found your answer. Mi solution only works one time because I used id instance of class.